# How to transform specific Java expression into Javascript expression?

Tags: javascript, java, regex

How I can transform this Java Expression into a Java Script Expression:

```
if(this.myStringValue != null && 
   !this.myStringValue.equals("") &&        
   !this.myStringValue.matches("[\\d]*")){

    // do something

}
```

'myStringValue' is a String in Java.

What is the same logic in JavaScript? Many thanks for helping me!

Comment: Don't you try on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this,

```
> var s = ''
undefined
> s != null && !s.match(/^\d*$/)
false
> var s = 'bar'
undefined
> s != null && !s.match(/^\d*$/)
true
> var s = '23'
undefined
> s != null && !s.match(/^\d*$/)
false
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be transformed into:

```
if (this.myStringValue != null && this.myStringValue != "" && !/\d*/.test(this.myStringValue) ){
    // do something
}
```

Anyway those tests make no sense. `[\\d]*` is always true. We can try with:

```
if ( this.myStringValue && !/\d+/.test(this.myStringValue) ) {}
```